# How to layout these elements via HTML/CSS circumventing DOMPDF's lack of float?

Tags: php, html, css, css-float, dompdf

The image below explains what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

I need to show a user's car picture with the name under it. Each image/name pair should be in a DIV so as a user adds more cars, they move to the next line or page. Ideally the DIVs should be centered, more as a matter of aesthetics.

Using [DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/), I am generating a PDF from an HTML layout.

Unfortunately, DOMPDF's support for float is bad, even in the new 0.6.2 beta. I wonder if this layout I am proposing could be done without float. DOMPDF also does not support unordered lists.

I have tried some solutions using tables, but this also isn't good since DOMPDF does not allow cells to spill over to the next page.

I am using PHP 5/ codeigniter, and DOMPDF 0.5.2 (stable).

Any suggestions on how to get this layout are greatly appreciated!

Here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        img {width: 150px; height: 150px;}

        h1 {font-size: 3em; text-align: center;}

        h2 {text-transform: uppercase; width: 150px; text-align: center;}

        div {margin: 10px; width: 150px;}

    </style>
</head>


    <h1>My Cars</h1>

        <?php foreach ($cars as $row): ?>

            <div>

                <img src="<?php echo $row->cars_picture; ?>" />

                <h2><?php echo $row->cars_name; ?></h2>

            </div>

        <?php endforeach; ?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @rkw and @manyxcxi for helping out.
At the end the only way of doing this without hacks was to use **[mpdf](http://mpdf.bpm1.com/)** instead of DOMPDF.

I have the impression mpdf is a much better library, with better documentation. It has partial support for `float`, but it works very nicely and does **exactly** what I needed above.

Answer (score 0):

If the boxes are all fixed width and you know the width of your PDF, then you can calculate the boxes per row and use a spacer div on the left of the bottom row to give you the offset you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Without using float, you would have to use  instead of : http://jsfiddle.net/AxZam/40/

relevant css:

```
body {
   width:800px; 
}
#content {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 600px;
    text-align: center;
}
img {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
}
.cars {
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    width:150px; 
    display:block; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0px; left:0px; }
span {
    margin: 10px; 
    position: relative;
}
```

relevant html section:

```
<div id='content'>
    <h1>My Cars</h1>
    <span>
        <img />
        <span class='cars'>car</span>
    </span>
    ...
</div>
```